# Label not showing up when I push view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

My label is not showing up when I push the view controller, does anyone know why and how to fix it?

```
@IBAction func tapButton (_ sender: Any) {

    let vc = UIViewController()
    Vc.view.backgroundColor = .gray
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    label.font = UIFont(name: “Arial”, size: 16.0)
    
    label.text = “Test label”
    
    Other label configurations...
    
    vc.view.addSubView(label)
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: You will have to share more details in order to get useful answers.

Comment: By changing adding a space on the second file sorted alphabetically reversed in the third line, at char 5. More seriously: Do we have to guess what's wrong? Show some code/screenshot of UI, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some constraints to your label (in order to position it on the second View Controller):

```
    @IBAction func buttonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "TestTest"
        
        vc.view.addSubview(label)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.centerYAnchor),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```